# Beginner with Genealogytree

Tags: genealogytree

I tried to run the tutorial program from page 16. The text of the tree members don't fit into the boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \genealogytree[template=signpost]{
  parent{
   g{first}
   c{second}
   c{third}
   p{father}
   p{mother}
  }
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The resulting picture of the dvi-file]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: the code shown above works fine for me

Comment: I  am sure my problem has nothing to do with the genealogytree-package. But what setup in my TeX, which runs fine otherwise, might be the cause

Comment: Are you by any chance looking at a DVI-file? Try generating a PDF with `pdflatex` and look at the PDF.

Comment: When using pdflatex the resulting pdf-file looks as expected. A dvi-file was not generated. Thank you for that hint, Torbjorn